# django : Serving static files through nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I'm using apache+mod_wsgi for django.
And all css/js/images are served through `nginx`.
For some odd reason, when others/friends/colleagues try accessing the site, jquery/css is not getting loaded for them, hence the page looks jumbled up.

My html files use code like this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://x.x.x.x:8000/css/custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1x.x.x.x:8000/js/custom.js"></script>
```

My nginx configuration in `sites-available` is like this -

```
    server {   
         listen   8000;   
         server_name  localhost;

         access_log  /var/log/nginx/aa8000.access.log;    
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/aa8000.error.log;    

           location / {   
               index  index.html index.htm;    
           }    

         location /static/ {    
            autoindex on;    
            root   /opt/aa/webroot/;    
         }    
     }
```

There is a directory `/opt/aa/webroot/static/` which have corresponding `css` & `js` directories.

The odd thing is that the pages show fine when I access them.
I have cleared my cache/etc, but the page loads fine for me, from various browsers.

Also, I don't see 404 any error in the nginx log files.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: I know it may be obvious but it wasnt for me, after you do the changes run: 
`sudo nginx -s reload`
That should make it work, it did for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. `server_name` must match hostname in `link`/`script` URLs. Either declare your configuration as default for this interface:port pair (`listen 8000 default`)
2. Nginx must listen on the interface where your host's IP is bound (seems ok in your case)

Comment: 3. URI of js/css and other static files should start with /static/ prefix in your html file, so that it can match to /static/ location block in your nginx conf.

Answer (score 95):

I think using `root` in location block is incorrect. I use `alias` and it works fine, even without re-configuring django.

```
# django settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

# nginx server config
server {   
    ...
    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /opt/aa/webroot/;    
    }
}
```

Hope this makes things simpler.

Comment: Indeed, `alias` is the proper method to serve entire directories.

Comment: Same works for me, because /static and /static/ are different locations and in second variant I always got permission error from nginx.

Comment: For anyone reading this. Nginx docs clearly state, that "When location matches the last part of the directive’s value it is better to use the root directive instead" http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias  Also see this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/278359

Comment: Awesome, thank you and I wish this was explained in a Passenger tutorial. It's taken me 4 days to find this information. Alias is the correct choice for me because the folder is called 'assets' not 'static', so you need to provide a completely different name not just a path.

Comment: In my case I have a trailing slash in the "location /static/ {}". Removing the trailing slash and using alias to the staticfiles path worked for me. It should be now "location /static { alias <path-to-static-files>}" then reload/restart nginx.

Answer (score 15):

I also struggled with this. However, following trick worked for me:

```
server {   
     listen   8000;   
     server_name  localhost;

     access_log  /var/log/nginx/aa8000.access.log;    
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/aa8000.error.log;    

       location / {   
           index  index.html index.htm;    
       }    

     location ^/static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        root   /opt/aa/webroot/;    
     }    
 }
```

I just marked static as a regex with `^` and nginx started serving static files. No modification on Django side was needed.

Answer (score 5):

MEDIA_URL shall not be used to serve the Static content like js etc. Django provides a separate STATIC_URL settings option that can be used.

So this can be changed as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also, its more standard to use staticfile app templatetag like this:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' %}"></script>
```

[Docs Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

Answer (score 4):

**Fim & Alexander** - Thanks for the hints those helped.
Here is how I solved it for anyone stuck in the same boat -

**settings.py** -

```
>MEDIA_ROOT = ''    
MEDIA_URL = 'http://x.x.x.x:8000/static/'
```

**In my html** -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

**In my views.py** -

```
return render_to_response('templates/login-register.html', {},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request));
```

**nginx** inside the sites-available config file -

```
listen x.x.x.x:8000;    
server_name x.x.x.x.;
```

**Restarted nginx**
**Restarted apache**

Comment: Unless you also have the "location /static" etc in your nginx conf Django will be serving the static files. Fine for testing and dev but not a good idea for production.