# How to server static django files using passenger wsgi

Tags: django, nginx, passenger, dreamhost, django-staticfiles

Background :

Am using Django. Am hosting my site on Dreamhost. Am using Nginx as the web server and passenger.wsgi.

Problem:

I have read that on production server we should server the static media from outside i.e. should not allow the django and python to server it.
What I want to do is server the static media file using passenger.Is that possible? If yes how?

P.S :- I have read that uwsgi+nginx is the best for this. But dreamhost does not support uwsgi.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451739/django-serving-static-files-through-nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static media should never have to go through passenger. Configure the web server with its equivalent of `Alias` to graft the static media into the proper location(s) within URL space.

Comment: Hi am not getting what you are saying?
Should i configure nginx with an alias for the static media location?