# cascading media_root and media_url

Tags: python, django, settings

I have an issue with a django project. We use a big disk to store images for years. Everyday users upload a lot of images on this disk.

Now the disk has some problems, and I want to send all the uploads to a new disk from now one. That's the easy part. The problem is if I change my settings, all the old images won't be accessible. To copy the images from the old disk is not a short term option, as we are talking about hundreds of terabytes...

My plan was to write the images on the new disk from now one, and when an app tries to read it, it should try on the new disk first, if the image is not there, fallback on the old disk.

Any ideas/advice on how to cascade settings properly? Is it even an option?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would basically put a lightweight server like nginx in front of the media server that will be responsible for handling this.

You can explore using `try_files` in nginx which can receive the media file argument and check it on disk1, disk2 and then failover.

Refer

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

[django : Serving static files through nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451739/django-serving-static-files-through-nginx)

Comment: Seems like a good idea... We already have nginx running there, but we lost our sysadmin, so I'll look it up myself.

Thanks !