# How do i implement pdf or doc file upload and downloads on a django project?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm creating a website where i can upload catalogues on a downloads page and users can download them, i can achieve this for a single file by using the following code in the view, but i need a simpler way i can do this on the admin or on a template.

```
def brochure(request):
 fs = FileSystemStorage()
 filename = 'kastom_profile.pdf'
 if fs.exists(filename):
    with fs.open(filename) as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename="kastom_profile.pdf"'
        return response
  else:
    return HttpResponseNotFound('The requested pdf was not found in our server.')
```

Comment: Are you running your server with apache? You could just serve the files with apache or any other webserver. Or do you want to stick to django for the whole project? If so, why?

Comment: I'm using nginx as my web server, I wanted to use django to do all the work since i didn't know there is another way to get around my problem.

Comment: Have a look at this question. It could help you set up nginx to serve files outside of django. Django can then just redirect to the requested files. This is the way django is intended to work so I suggest you have a look at this.

Comment: i'd be very grateful if you guided me through the whole process of setting up nginx, you haven't provided a link to the question though

Comment: oops, sorry. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451739/django-serving-static-files-through-nginx you can find many tutorials on how to setup nginx with django. Just search for it on google :)