# Django - CSS File Not Loading In Production server (Debug: False)

Tags: css, django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Use : nginx,gunicorn,linode for server

**Debug=False**

When I keep debug=False in production the css file don't get loaded.I have also build 404.html page.Suppose some one visit mydomain.com/abcd then he/she will get the 404 page which I have designed.Its good.The issue is css file not loaded.

**Debug True**

When I keep debug=True in the production the css file get loaded.Everything goes right.But when someone visited the mydomain.com/abcd then he/she will get the django defaualt error page.If I keep debug=True in the production everything goes right but I have heard that keeping debug=True in production is not recommended and may cause the security issues in the sites

Currently what I have in my settings.py and nginx cofig are :

**settings.py :**

```
DEBUG =True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ip','mydomain.com','www.mydomain.com']
```

**Nginx config file :**

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location projectdir/static/ {
        autoindex on ;
        root /home/user/projectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

Please help me to solve the issue,since I am struggling from past 1 week.
Currently the site is live and css is loaded by keeping debug=True.But I don't want to have any security issue later.

Comment: Django does not serve static content when **DEBUG** is set to **False** that's where nginx comes in play you've to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133910/14457833) or read nginx [doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/).

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py file:

You can simply add like below code:

```
DEBUG = bool(int(os.environ.get('DEBUG', 0))) #Note: 0 means false and 1 means true
```

Try this way and check if this is solves your error

Comment: Isn't this same as keeping debug=False?

Comment: I have used this code as you provided in my settings.py but it didn''t work

Answer (score 0):

config required in your settings.py

```
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

make sure you've run the following, so django finds all your static files and puts them in one place

```
$python manage.py collectstatic
```

nginx static config should look more like

```
...
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/user/projectdir/static/;
}
```